# Does forgetting colimits preserve colimits?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, limits-and-colimits

For each regular cardinal $\kappa$ let $\operatorname{Cat}_{\kappa}$ be the $(2,1)$-category of small categories with $\kappa$-small colimits, and functors that preserve those colimits. For each pair of regular cardinals $\tau > \kappa$ there is an evident forgetful functor $U_{\tau, \kappa}: \operatorname{Cat}_{\tau} \rightarrow \operatorname{Cat}_\kappa$. It can be seen that $U_{\tau,\kappa}$ preserves $\kappa$-small coproducts, as these can be computed in terms of $\kappa$-small products, which are preserved by virtue of the fact that $U_{\tau,\kappa}$ is a right adjoint.

**Question:** Does $U_{\tau,\kappa}$ preserve all $\kappa$-small colimits?

Feel free to assume $\kappa$ to be uncountable or even bigger if it helps. I'm ultimately interested in the $\infty$-categorical version of this question so answers in that context are welcome as well.

Comment: What sort of colimits? All weak 2-colimits? Or just those that can be built from coproducts coinserters and coequifers? Etc.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I had in mind all weak 2-colimits. I also want to consider these as (weak) $(2,1)$-categories, and since $U_{\tau, \kappa}$ already preserves $\kappa$ small coproducts, the question really reduces to whether it also preserves weak coequalizers.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking, but it might be easier to break that down from weak coequalisers to other specific colimits that generate all weak 2-colimits.

Comment: As you may know, if you work with 2-categories rather than (2,1)-categories, then the argument showing that the forgetful functor preserves $\kappa$-small coproducts also shows that it preserves Kleisli objects and $\kappa$-small *lax* colimits, since these are also absolute and can be computed in terms of limits.  This doesn't answer your question however.  I would be surprised if the answer is yes.

Comment: @MikeShulman That's interesting. So I guess your claim is that Kleisli objects in $\operatorname{Cat}_\kappa$ are computed in terms of Eilenberg-Moore objects, which are preserved by the forgetful functor since they are weighted limits, and then an arbitrary $\kappa$-small lax colimit in $\operatorname{Cat}_\kappa$ can be written as the Kleisli object of a certain monad on a $\kappa$-small coproduct, so it is also preserved.

Comment: I agree a positive answer to the original question would be surprising. There are different weakenings one could imagine that might have a better chance of being true: for instance, given a $\kappa$-small diagram $F: \mathcal{I} \rightarrow\operatorname{Cat}_\tau$ one could ask whether the map $\operatorname{colim} U_{\tau,\kappa} F \rightarrow U_{\tau,\kappa} \operatorname{colim} F$ is necessarily surjective/fully faithful/a localization.

Comment: Yes; see for instance section 15 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3191.

Comment: When $\kappa = 0$ (so that $Cat_\kappa = Cat$), the answer is _no_ for any infinite $\tau$. For instance, consider the inclusion $f : \ast \to (\to)$ into the arrow category of its initial object, which preserves all colimits. The pushout of $f$ against itself in $Cat$ is the walking span, which does not have finite colimits. So it differs from the pushout computed in $Cat_\tau$ for any infinite $\tau$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example showing that $U_{\tau, \kappa}$ does not preserve pushouts for any pair of regular cardinals $\tau > \kappa$. Let $C = \tau$, where here $\tau$ is thought of as an ordinal (i.e. the smallest ordinal of cardinality $\tau$) and $C$ is regarded as a category where there is an arrow $x \rightarrow y$ if and only if $x \leq y$.  Using the ordinal identity $2 \cdot \tau = \tau$ we may construct full subcategories $C_0$ and $C_1$ of $C$ where $C_i$ contains those objects that correspond to elements of $2 \cdot \tau$ of the form $(x, i)$. The inclusions $C_i \rightarrow C$ admit left adjoints, so we have a span $C_0 \leftarrow C \rightarrow C_1$ inside $\operatorname{Cat}_{\tau}$. Let $D_\tau$ be its pushout, and let $D_\kappa$ be the pushout of its image under $U_{\tau, \kappa}$. We will show that $D_\tau \neq D_\kappa$.

The object $D_\tau$ in $\operatorname{Cat}_{\tau}$ is defined by the following property: for each $E$ in $\operatorname{Cat}_{\tau}$, the category of $\tau$-small colimit preserving functors $D_\tau \rightarrow E$ is equivalent to the category of $\tau$-small colimit preserving functors $C \rightarrow E$ which factor through the localizations $C \rightarrow C_i$. The latter is the same as the category of $\tau$-small colimit preserving functors which invert the arrow $x \rightarrow x+1$ for every $x$ in $C$. A functor has this property if and only if it is the left Kan extension of its restriction along $\emptyset \rightarrow C$. It follows that $D_\tau$ is the initial object of $\operatorname{Cat}_\tau$, so that $D_\tau$ is the singleton category.

Arguing as above, to show that $D_\kappa \neq D_\tau$ it now suffices to show that there is an object $E$ in $\operatorname{Cat}_\kappa$ and a non-constant $\kappa$-small colimit preserving functor $F: C \rightarrow E$ which inverts the arrow $x \rightarrow x + 1$ for every $x$ in $C$. We may take $E = 2$ to be the walking arrow, and $F$ to be the functor sending $x$ to $0$ if and only if $x < \kappa$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to play around with, with $\kappa = \omega$ and $\tau = \omega_1$ and $Vect = Vect_k$ for $k$ a finite field, look at the pushout of $Vect \leftarrow Set \to Vect$, where both functors are the free functor. The question becomes whether $$Ind(Vect_{\omega_1} \times_{Set_{\omega_1}} Vect_{\omega_1}) \to Ind(Vect_{\omega_1}) \times_{Ind(Vect_{\omega_1})} Ind(Vect_{\omega_1})$$
is an equivalence. I think maybe it's not essentially surjective: the domain consists of Ind-systems of countable-sets-equipped-with-two-vector-space-structures, whereas the codomain consists of ind-countable-sets-equipped-with-two-ind-countable-vector-space-structures. If we restrict to $\omega$-indexed ind-systems, it already looks problematic to try to rectify the latter to the former.

---

(**EDIT:** The following argument is problematic --see the comments below.) Maybe the answer is actually *yes*?

Translating across the equivalence $Ind_\kappa : Cat_\kappa {}^\to_\leftarrow Pr^L_\kappa : (-)_\kappa$ (and similarly for $\tau$), we are asking whether the functor $\Phi: \mathcal K \mapsto Ind_\kappa(U^\tau_\kappa(\mathcal K_\tau)) : Pr^L_\tau \to Pr^L_\kappa$ preserves pushouts. Since $\Pr^L_\kappa$ and $Pr^L_\tau$ are closed under colimits in $Pr^L$, we may compute our pushouts there.

So consider a span $B \xleftarrow F A \xrightarrow G C$ in $Pr^L_\tau$, and let $F^\ast, G^\ast$ be the right adjoints of $F, G$ respectively. The pushout of this span in $Pr^L$ is the pullback $B \times_A C$ computed in $Cat$ using $F^\ast, G^\ast$. For some regular cardinal $\rho \geq \tau$ which is large enough that $F^\ast, G^\ast$ preserve $\rho$-compact objects, consider the fully faithful inclusion $Y^\ast : A \to A' = Ind_\tau(A_\rho)$, with left adjoint $Y$. Then the pullback is equally $B \times_{A'} C$, since $Y^\ast : A \to A'$ is fully faithful. Moreover, $(FY)^\ast$ and $(GY)^\ast$ preserve $\tau$-compact objects.

Now, the pushout of $\Phi B \xleftarrow{\Phi F} \Phi A \xrightarrow{\Phi G} \Phi C$ in $Pr^L$ is the pullback in $Cat$ $\Phi B \times_{\Phi A} \Phi C$, computed using the right adjoints $(\Phi F)^\ast, (\Phi G)^\ast$. Since $\Phi$ is a left 2-adjoint, it preserves localizations. Since $Y$ is a localization, so is $\Phi Y$, and thus $(\Phi Y)^\ast$ is fully faithful. So this pullback is equally $\Phi B \times_{\Phi A'} \Phi C$.

In other words, we have reduced to the case where $F^\ast$ and $G^\ast$ preserve $\tau$-compact objects. Note that $(-)_\tau$ is in fact 2-functorial in all functors preserving $\tau$-compact objects, and $U^\tau_\kappa$ and $Ind_\kappa$ are 2-functorial in all functors (in the sense that they carry functors to functors and natural transformations to natural transformations coherently). Moreover, these functors commute with pullbacks as computed in $Cat$ -- $(-)_\tau$ and $U^\tau_\kappa$ preserve all limits in this sense while $Ind_\kappa$ preserves $\kappa$-small limits as a functor $Cat \to Cat$. So $\Phi$, as the composite of these functors, likewise preserves the relevant $Cat$-pullback as desired.

Comment: The proof I know of $\operatorname{Ind}_\kappa$ preserving pullbacks of categories seems to require at least some preservation of colimits by the functors involved. For instance HTT proposition 5.4.6.6 begins with a cospan in the image of $\operatorname{Ind}_\kappa$ but only shows that the pullback is in the image of $\operatorname{Ind}_\tau$ for some $\tau \gg \kappa$.

Comment: It seems to me that $\operatorname{Ind}_\kappa$ in fact does not preserve all pullbacks. For example, let $C = \kappa$ (thought of as an ordinal and in particular as a category) and let $C_0$, $C_1$ be disjoint cofinal full subcategories of $C$. Then the pullback $C_0 \times_C C_1$ is not preserved by $\operatorname{Ind}_\kappa$.

Comment: @G.Stefanich Yeah, I guess you're right.